# Can I access Large Number data type in Access 2016 file using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB provider?

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

In my .Net app, I use a Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider to read data from Access files.
Everything had been working fine, until I faced the need to read data from file containing Large Number column type. (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-the-Large-Number-data-type-5b623f6e-641d-4e97-8bdf-b77bae076f70) I've installed the latest Database Engine (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920 , 32-bit version) and followed the instructions. Still, I'm getting next error when opening the connection to that file:

**System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException**: 'The database you are trying to open requires a newer version of Microsoft Access.'

Is Large Number supported in OLEDB provider?

Note: I've also tried using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 provider (instruction tells to use 12.0) and got same results.

Note 2: I've tried using the latest release of Database Engine 2010. Same problem.

Comment: is your app 64bit?

Comment: Hi BugFinder. No, it is 32-bit.

Comment: Does this article help? https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Using-the-Large-Number-data-type-5b623f6e-641d-4e97-8bdf-b77bae076f70

Comment: I've readen the article, and it tells that if I have MS Access of version higher than 16.7, I can open the database. It is true, file can be opened through the MS Access. Hovewer, when I'm trying to use the OLEDB provider to get data programmatically, I get an error. Thanks @BugFinder

Comment: but what exact version is the access engine - vs maybe having actual access installed?

Comment: I've tried latest releases of both MS Access Database Engine 2016 and 2010, and I get the same problem with both of them. @BugFinder

Comment: Ah, I suggested actually installing ms access.. not the engine..

Comment: We've tried that, didn't help either. @BugFinder

Comment: well thats kinda me out of ideas with the info i have.  You could raise a request with MS

Comment: You might try a quick test with `System.Data.Odbc` and the latest version of the ODBC driver for Access 2016 to see if that works any better.

Comment: FWIW, I just installed the latest [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920), released 2017-03-15, and the ODBC driver reports version 16.00.4513. If your ODBC driver (with a full Access 2016 install) reports the same version then the OLEDB and ODBC components may not have been updated (yet?).

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks for the comment. You were right, there is no support for the format in OLEDB yet.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I've gotten an answer from MSFT CSG, you can view it here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c314519b-d972-43ac-9a04-29cae19413b8/can-i-access-large-number-data-type-in-access-2016-file-using-microsoftaceoledb-provider?forum=accessdev

TLDR: As of 8 Aug 2017, the component (aceoledb.dll) **does not support** Large Number data type.